# Is there a way to make C# read integers and strings in the same line?

Tags: c#, string, integer

I'm trying to make this program:

[image]

I'm not sure if I should use an if else or some sort of loop or both. This is my first programming course so any help would be great.

Here is what I have so far it works but its not what I want.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Assignment_3
{
class Program
{
    static void Exercise1(){


    }

    static void Exercise2()
    {

        double number;
        string character;
        Console.Write("Enter an integer or 'q' to quit ");
        number = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        character = Console.ReadLine();
        if (number >= 1 && number <= 10 || character =="q")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Coool");

        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Your number must be between 1 and 10");
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Exercise1();

        Exercise2();

        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to end");
        Console.ReadLine();
    } 
}
}
```

Comment: SO is wrong place to look for "any help" - if you have concrete question - makes sure to ask it by updating your post, otherwise deleting the post while it still have 0 score may be good idea.

Comment: The result of `Console.ReadLine()` is a string. You can store the string value in a variable, and check to see if it is equal to `q` independent of parsing the string as a number.

Comment: I did. It's in the title of the question and then I asked if I should use a loop to achieve what I was wanting. The "any help" part was to help clearify I'm new to this and I'm not really sure what I need to do to achieve this program so I was simply stating that I will literally take any suggestions for help.

Comment: @RyanHunt If the answer I provided is satisfactory, then please accept it. Otherwise, if you have any questions let us know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static void Exercise2()
    {


        string entry;
        Console.Write("Enter an integer or 'q' to quit: ");
        entry = Console.ReadLine();
        while (entry.ToLower() != "q")
        {
            int number;
            if (int.TryParse(entry, out number))
            {
                if (number >= 1 && number <= 10)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Coool");

                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Your number must be between 1 and 10");
                }
            }

            Console.Write("Enter an integer or 'q' to quit: ");
            entry = Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the result of ReadLine() as a variable and evaluate it, checking for "q" then, if that doesn't work, parse the variable as an int.